# set long timeout for selected session variable

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-2.0, session-timeout

net 2.0 and I want admin session variable timeout for 1 hour.

Is it possible? and How?

I am using windows authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the session timeout globally in web.config:

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <sessionState 
      mode="InProc"
      cookieless="true"
      timeout="30" />
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

And you can programmatically override that setting in your code (e.g. for the admin's session only), by setting Session.Timeout, e.g:

```
// set the current session's timeout to 60 minutes
// if the current user is an admin
if (currentUserIsAdmin)
    Session.Timeout = 60;
```

Have a look at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.sessionstate.httpsessionstate.timeout.aspx) for details.

Comment: Martin, If i programmmatically change on above condition then, will it affect globally? Like if admin session is created then all the other session will have timeout 60 min! otherwise 30 min

Comment: No, if you set the timeout programmatically, you do it only for one session (the current session).